# performing .net postback on jquery ui tab selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a set of tabs on my web form using JQueryUI tabs.

When I click on a tab, I want the data on that tab to load (only when I click on the tab). As I don't want to load all tab data on initial page load.

I have used a linkbutton on the tab, so that when I click on the tab, the button click event should fire and cause a post back. But this does not happen.

My question is. Does the JQueryUI tab pluggin disable the default action of the link in the tab? I noticed that if I don't use an anchor link of some sort in the tab li element that the tab is not rendered properly, so JQuery obviously requires an anchor to render.

How can I get my data to load only when the tab is selected?

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

content via ajax in right hand menu

then you can do something like

ajaxpostback.ashx?page=page1

and then you are only returning intended content

code example

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
    <li><a href="Handler1.ashx?page=1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="Handler1.ashx?page=2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="Handler1.ashx?page=3">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
    <li><a href="Handler1.ashx?page=4">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>
       Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
</div>
```

Handler

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (string.Compare(context.Request.QueryString["page"].ToString(), "1") == 0)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("1");
        }
        else if (string.Compare(context.Request.QueryString["page"].ToString(), "2") == 0)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("2");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("rest");
        }
    }
```